# Why do (most) metals cause problems in a microwave oven? Which metals (if any) don't?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, metals, antennas, microwaves

Most of us have seen microwave ovens with metal racks or shelves, which challenges the common notion that you can't (safely) put metal in a microwave oven.  What's going on here?  Is it a matter of these shelves being made of a specific metal (if so what are the properties that allow it to be used in a microwave oven?) or of being placed in just the right place in relation to the waves that will be emitted, or something else entirely?

If it is a matter of using just the right metal (or alloy), then which metals are okay to use in a microwave oven?

Comment: The shape of the metal is more important than the type.  Wikipedia covers it well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Metal_objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67880/