# Why does an aluminum foil spark inside a microwave oven?

Tags: everyday-life, microwaves

I did an experiment today. I put an aluminum foil inside the microwave oven thinking that nothing would happen. But contrary to my expectations it started sparking badly. I looked for answers on the internet but none of them were very satisfactory and explainatory at the same time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do metal objects in microwaves spark?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67880/)

Comment: i think the article on wikipedia should be adequate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Hazards

Answer (score 1):

Microwave ovens use radio waves to heat food. Quite a lot of them, around 1000 to 1500 watts, all of that trapped inside a metal box. Contrast that to a powerful radio station at 50,000 W that sends it off into space, so [by the time it gets to you its microwatts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331725/how-much-power-does-a-receiver-antenna-obtain-from-a-radio-station).

Antennas work because an electrical field "induces" an electric current in a conductor. Antennas are made of conductors, typically aluminum (sometimes copper or steel). Radio waves are, in effect, a combination of electrical and magnetic fields. When the electrical part goes by the antenna it induces a current in it. You pick up that current in a wire and amplify the freak out of it.

Now what might happen if you put a TV antenna, which is used to getting microwatts of energy, inside a microwave oven where there's thousands of watts? Maybe you'll get a WHOLE FREAKLOAD of current?

And what happens to the temperature of conductors when they carry a WHOLE FREAKLOAD of current?

And what did you put in the microwave? Aluminum you say?